# Adding multiple 'Limit to hosts matching' for user in Workbench

Tags: mysql

I want to add two IP addresses to limit a user account in Workbench. I can't figure out the syntax. I've scanned the help and online.

`123.456.789.123, 127.0.0.1` doesn't work. It says `Hosts` so I'm assuming it's possible without creating a new user for each host limit.

Whatever I try I get a `Invalid host specification` error.

Also I can't add Workbench as a tag here.

Comment: it says "hosts" because an address with a wildcard can match multiple hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I'm assuming it's possible without creating a new user for each host limit.` - That would be an invalid assumption.  There is one entry in the 'user' table for each 'Host,User' combination.

Just do a `select * from mysql.user where user='root'` note the multiple 'root' accounts for localhost, 127.0.0.1, and so on that show up in the default configuration.

```
mysql> select Host,User,Password from mysql.user where user='root';
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host      | User | Password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| 127.0.0.1 | root | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| ::1       | root | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. I see only one record returned for that query. Can I enter multiple hosts in the Workbench user setup? If so how? Cheers!

Comment: Right, so only one host per user. Odd that it uses the word 'hosts' implying plural then.

Comment: It is kind of an annoying design decision on the part of Mysql.  These days I have basically giving up on using Mysql to restrict access by host and just use `'%'` in my host fields, and restrict things at the firewall level for the post part.

Comment: Yeah good idea. I use a firewall too but have this as a last line of defense.

Comment: What does the ::1 mean for host?

Comment: @Vincent `::1` is the IPv6 localhost/loopback address, like `127.0.0.1` is for IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I hope what I found in an official document can make contribution to help  u solve it !

As for my answer, I would like to suggest that u should pay attention to these three scope of MySQL System table elements:**Host**, **User**, and **authentication_string**,which I think is the key of making limit access !

[MySQL 5.7 Access Control](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html)

Hope u can greatly solve problem!